# Rails select required

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, select

I see such select tag in my rails view partial:

```
= f.select :shipping_id, options_for_select(["Select"] + @shippings.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}), :required => true
```

And what i wont to do is this:
If page load's, this select show only "Select me please :D", and i must select some value from select, not this ("Select me please :D"), and if i have selected or default "Select me please :D", i get error, or something like this?
It must be something like placeholder, which value hides, if i click on this select? I know how to do this in jQuery, but wanna do in rails view

Answer (score 0):

```
= f.select :shipping_id, [["Select Me", "Value for Jquery to attach to"]] + @shippings.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}, {:required => true}
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, but i have on this select jquery event called change, so that if in this list i click on select me, jquery react on this, but i wanna that on promt jquery doesn't react, becouse it is html promt, not list item