# Rails Form Select Required

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to have a `<select>` be required in my Rails form.

This is my code (elipsis is to make line shorter):

```
<div class="field">
  <p><%= f.label :category, "Category:" %></p>
  <%= f.select :category, ['Analytics','Commerce',..., 'Web'], :prompt => '-- Select One --', :required => true %>
</div>
```

Which outputs

```
<div class="field">
  <p><label for="startup_category">Category:</label></p>
  <select id="startup_category" name="startup[category]">
    <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
    <option value="Analytics">Analytics</option>
    <option value="Commerce">Commerce</option>
    <option value="Content Management">Content Management</option>
    <option value="Gaming">Gaming</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Media">Media</option>
    <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
    <option value="Technology - Software">Technology - Software</option>
    <option value="Technology - Hardware">Technology - Hardware</option>
    <option value="Web">Web</option></select>
</div>
```

Putting `{:required => true}` instead of `:required => true` gives a syntax error and `{:prompt => '-- Select One --', :required => true}` renders the page, but without the `required="true"` in my select tag.

How can I get `required="true"` in my tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11951873/rails-select-required

i think this the same question

Comment: @leef Putting {:required => true} instead of :required => true gives a syntax error and {:prompt => '-- Select One --', :required => true} renders the page, but without the required="true" in my select tag.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

try this one....

```
f.select :category, ['Analytics','Commerce',..., 'Web'], { :include_blank => '-- Select One --' }, :required => true
```

Comment: I actually JUST figured this out!  I put curly braces around `:required => true` as well, but I'm not sure if they're necessary. Thanks for the help regardless.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for but the syntax is  bit different `f.select :category, ['Analytics','Commerce',..., 'Web'], { include_blank:  '-- Select One --' }, required: true
`

Comment: I've tried every other answer I can possibly find and this is the only one that worked. Such a bizarre and unintuitive syntax. Quite unusual for Railsy stuff.

Answer (score 4):

For **Rails 4**

```
    f.select :category,
      ['Analytics','Commerce',..., 'Web'],
      {
        include_blank: '-- Select One --' ,
        required: true
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it accomplish what you want, but I have two solutions for you. You can use simpleform gem.

OR

Style it:

```
<label class="required">Category</label>
```

The in css:

```
label.required:after{content:"*"}
```